# Is there an estimate for the greatest element in a row of Pascal's triangle

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm playing around with generating rows of Pascal Triangle.  I want to know, given a fixed-width integer type, the maximum row I can calculate before any individual element would be too big.

The sum of the elements of a row *n* of the triangle add up to 2^n.  So calculating row 64 on a 64-bit computer would be safe.  But how much further?  With signed arithmetic, I got to 66 as the last row, and 67 as last for unsigned arithmetic.  Is there a way to estimate how big the middle element(s) would be so I know the maximum row *r* given bit size *n*?

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Comment: Stirling theorem yields $\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$.

Comment: Use Stirling's [approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)